# How to select second div using jQuery in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If a webpage has 2 div tags like

```
<div>hello</div>
<div>hello</div>
```

How could I select second div, is it possible using jQuery?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The following will get the second div using the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) method:

```
$("div:eq(1)");
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/GM2s8/)**

Please note that @Cerbrus's answer is also correct, you can do this without jQuery.

Comment: Good call @ChrisLevine, I added a link in the answer the the jQuery page for `eq`

Answer (score 8):

You don't need jQuery:

```
var secondDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
```

`getElementsByTagName('div')` gets an array of all `div`s on the page, then you get the second element out of that (zero-indexed) array with `[1]`.

You could also apply a jQuery wrapper, if you need jQuery functionality:

```
var $secondDiv = $(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1]); //($ in the var name is merely used to indicate the var contains a jQuery object)
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HS3vp/)**

Comment: Thanks, but if I'm must required to do this using jQurey

Comment: @Mobi Why? jQuery is slower than native JS, you can always use the wrapper if you need jQuery functionality.

Comment: Yup, you are right, but it was part of my test. That's why I was asking to do using jQuery, thanks

Comment: Ah, fair enough :P In that case, @chase's answer is probably what you / the test are looking for. Although, in my opinion, mine's the better answer  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Stangely the `:nth-child` did not work for me.  I ended up using

`$(someElement).find("select").eq(0)`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `nth-child` selector.

http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: Badcat, SO answers should be self-contained. Please provide a example, instead of basically saying "rtfm".